# MySQL VARCHAR Lengths and UTF-8

Tags: mysql, unicode, utf-8, varchar

In MySQL, if I create a new `VARCHAR(32)` field in a UTF-8 table does it means I can store 32 bytes of data in that field or 32 chars (multi-byte)?

Comment: @naXa: I didn't. You think I should?

Comment: I don't know.) It's your question, and it's up to you. I just wanted to say "another answer looks more complete".

Comment: @robsch The previous accepted answer was simple and correct. But do to popular demand I've accepted the one you want.

Answer (score 190, accepted):

This answer showed up at the top of my google search results but wasn't correct.

The **confusion** is probably due to different versions of MySQL being tested.

- Version 4 counts bytes
- Version 5 counts characters

Here is the quote from the official MySQL 5 [documentation](https://web.archive.org/web/20160425203826/https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-type-overview.html):

> MySQL interprets length specifications in character column definitions in character units. (Before MySQL 4.1, column lengths were interpreted in bytes.) This applies to CHAR, VARCHAR, and the TEXT types.

Interestingly (I hadn't thought about it) the max length of a varchar column is affected by utf8 as follows:

> The effective maximum length of a VARCHAR in MySQL 5.0.3 and later is subject to the maximum row size (65,535 bytes, which is shared among all columns) and the character set used. For example, utf8 characters can require up to three bytes per character, so a VARCHAR column that uses the utf8 character set can be declared to be a maximum of 21,844 characters.

Comment: M Brown, thanks for mentioning this. A VARCHAR(10) field (using `utf8mb4`) can store "" (10 piles of poo), that's 10 characters but 40 bytes.

Comment: This.  This is the only right answer.  Far too many people believe the version 4 behavior as gospel.

Comment: The accepted answer is also correct for MySQL 5 -- the numbers inserted were actually part of the full-width char set and are multi-byte unicode characters, as also mentioned by the poster that he inserted "32 multibytes data". It's a shame so many people misunderstood.

Comment: Citing the following source, I believe a utf8 character currently requires up to 6 bytes so anywhere between 1 and 6 bytes. This causes the worst case for a character maximum to be 10922. I think.

http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html

Comment: @usumoio Currently, it looks like MySQL uses the 3-byte variant of UTF-8, with migration to the (standard) 4-byte variant being planned: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/charset-unicode-utf8.html.

Comment: And this answer applies to MariaDB, too (perhaps expected): https://mariadb.com/kb/en/varchar/.

Answer (score 11):

it would let you store 32 multi-byte chars

> To save space with UTF-8, use
>   VARCHAR instead of CHAR. Otherwise,
>   MySQL must reserve three bytes for
>   each character in a CHAR CHARACTER SET
>   utf8 column because that is the
>   maximum possible length. For example,
>   MySQL must reserve 30 bytes for a
>    CHAR(10) CHARACTER SET utf8 column.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-unicode.html

Comment: I almost never use `CHAR` and when I do it's not intended to store  multi-byte chars, so I'm safe. What about `VARCHAR`, are you sure the limit is defined in multi-byte chars and not on single-byte chars?

Comment: @jspcal: UTF-8 uses a maximum of 4 bytes per character, not 3.  Or does MySQL not support all 4 bytes?

Comment: @RemyLebeau You are right about utf8, but not for MySQL. The various utf8_xxx character sets are 3-byte maximum. The utf8mb4_xxx take 4 byte characters. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/charset-unicode-utf8mb4.html

Comment: With the progression of time, it looks like MySQL will finally use the standard 4-byte version (but not yet, at the time of writing): https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/charset-unicode-utf8.html.

Answer (score 7):

32 ***multibytes*** data for `varchar(32)` with collation `utf8_unicode_ci`, I just tested with XAMPP.

```
１２３４５６７８９０１２３４５６７８９０１２３４５６７８９０１２３４５６７８９０
```

Get truncated to:

```
１２３４５６７８９０１２３４５６７８９０１２３４５６７８９０１２
```

Keep in mind that these are not regular ASCII chars.

Comment: In UTF-8 standard ASCII chars will only be stored in a single byte - to really test this you need to actually use some multibyte (ie. non-ascii) chars in your test sting.

Comment: This is wrong, at least for MySQL 5+. When specifying column size for varchar or char, it is specified in terms of characters. I believe the actual size of a VARCHAR(32) column would be 32x3+1=97 bytes.

Comment: @rjmackay '１２３４５' are not standard ASCII chars. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halfwidth_and_Fullwidth_Forms_(Unicode_block)

Comment: I inserted 40 unicode characters into DB, and got truncated at 32 character. But looks like people think I used ascii bytes and get truncated at 32 bytes. No wonder, I got downvotes, lol.

Comment: @ButtleButkus " I believe the actual size of a VARCHAR(32) column would be 32x3+1=97 bytes"   It would if you use `utf8`, but then you get broken Unicode support in MySQL. You should use `utf8mb4` encoding instead, because there are [max. 4 bytes in a utf-8 char](https://stijndewitt.wordpress.com/2014/08/09/max-bytes-in-a-utf-8-char/), not 3 as in MySQL's variant of utf8...

Comment: Version 4.0 (and before) had no real concept of `CHARACTER SET`.  4.1 was the first time you could apply a charset to a column/table/database.  That is, 4.0 mostly equated "byte" and "character".

Comment: @YOU - it isn't clear from your description whether the characters you inserted are encoded **in UTF-8** as 1-byte or as multi-byte. (Hence the downvotes) Can you clarify what unicode codes you inserted?  My first read of what you wrote is that you inserted &#049; (`1`), etc. And merely spaced them out so that they were easier to see. In which case, rjmackay would be correct, because UTF-8 is a variable-length encoding. But Alexey suggests you were indicating *fullwidth form characters* U+FF11 etc.

Comment: ... to clarify further, even if you created the Unicode as multi-byte characters, at the time of insertion into the UTF-8 field, the UTF-8 standard specifies *only the shortest possible encoding is allowed*. For example, if a character *can* be represented in a single UTF-8 byte, then it is *required* to be so encoded. [This was done to maximize backwards compatibility with ASCII readers.] So you may *think* you are "inserting multi-byte characters", but whether you really are, depends on the values of the character codes.

Answer (score 1):

It is better to use "char" for high-frequent update tables because the total data length of the row will be fixed and fast. Varchar columns make row data sizes dynamic. That's not good for MyISAM, but I don't know about InnoDB and others. For example, if you have a very narrow "type" column, it may be better to use char(2) with latin1 charset to only claim minimal space.

Comment: I've read that if ANY column in a table is varchar, then you lose all benefit of having char columns. Basically, it seems like you have to go with all varchar or all char in a table for maximum benefit. I don't know if it's true, though.

Comment: For MyISAM there is _some_ argument for `CHAR`.  For InnoDB, so many other things are going on that the "dynamic/fixed row size" debate is essentially irrelevant.

Comment: IMHO the important point here is that for *very small* lengths, it may be beneficial to use `CHAR`.

Answer (score 0):

If you connect to the database using latin1 encoding (for example with PHP) to save an PHP UTF8 string in an MySQL UTF8 column, you will have a double UTF8 encoding.

If the UTF8 string `$s` is 32 characters long but 64 bytes long and the column is `VARCHAR(32)` UTF8, the double encoding will convert the string `$s` to a 64 characters long UTF8 string that will be truncated in the database to its 32 first characters corresponding to the 32 first bytes of `$s`. You may end up thinking that MySQL 5 behaves like MySQL 4 but it is in fact a second cause for the same effect.