# Do need to consider differences between PHP & MySQL string lengths (eg. Single Byte vs Multi Byte characters)

Tags: php, mysql, validation

I am wondering if I were to validate a string that will be inserted into MySQL, do I need to consider single vs multi byte characters? I wonder if I can assume that a string that has a `strlen()` of 20 can be inserted into a MySQL `varchar(20)`?

Answer (score 2):

In mysql you specify the number of *characters* (they can be multibyte), whereas `strlen()` measures the length of string supposing that char == byte.

So if your string `strlen() == 20` then you **always** can insert it into `varchar(20)` since it is the same length or shorter actually (20 bytes <= 20 characters).

Answer (score 1):

It depends MySQL version and encoding of your column.

If using MySQL 4, it's number of bytes, and you can use strlen to count them.

If using MySQL 5, and using utf8 tables, it's number of chars, and then you need to use a multibyte aware function like [mb_strlen](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-strlen.php) to count chars in your string.

See [MySQL VARCHAR Lengths and UTF-8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1997540/mysql-varchar-lengths-and-utf-8) for more details.

Comment: "I wonder if I can assume that a string" --- i think that he doesn't need `mb_strlen`

Comment: The same, ok ;-) Btw, good point about mysql4. I've almost already forgotten there is something other than mysql5.1