# Confusing in declaring Varchar for unicode when creating table in MYSQL?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I want to store "First name" with max length of 12 characters. If it exceeds, it will be rejected.

So, I create a table with this schema

```
create table Tb (firstName varchar(12) character set utf8 NOT NULL)
```

Now if the name is in ASCII, then it will be fine. But what if it's in Japanese or Thai? Each Unicode char takes 3 bytes, so do I need to triple the size like this?

```
create table Tb (firstName varchar(36) character set utf8 NOT NULL)
```

But then, if I triple the size like that, then the English users can put a name that is longer than 12 chars. How to solve this issue?

Comment: Why don't you validate the input before inserting to the DB?

Comment: *How to solve this issue?* - **Is it** really an issue? My full first name has 14 ASCII characters. If I can't fill out my first name in a textfield used for online billing, **that** would be a real issue -  when the customer is not able to give you his money.

Comment: maybe this helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1997540/mysql-varchar-lengths-and-utf-8

Answer (score -2):

It's always better to use `varchar(255)` at least when you are not so sure about your field length.

Comment: but then we still not understand how they count the bytes?

Comment: Thats why i used AT LEAST. Now its upto you how much you want to give. :) But in general a name should fit in perfectly.

Comment: You can take a look at this article to get an idea http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode