# Mysql Varchar fields lengths Byte or Characters

Tags: mysql, utf-8, varchar

I am new with Mysql and character set and having some doubpts.

I have one Column which is:

```
VARHCAR(250) and CHARACTER SET = utf8
```

Now does `VARCHAR(250)` means that I can save `250 byte`s or `250 UTF8` characters.

If it means that I can store `250 UTF8` characters, because max size of UTF8 character is 3 byte does it means that I can store `250*3 bytes`?

What I want to do in my code is to check Length before inserting value in DB and reject it if it's too long. But I am not sure if I have to check characters length of byte length.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1997540/mysql-varchar-lengths-and-utf-8

Comment: `CHAR_LENGTH(...)` counts _characters_; `LENGTH(...)` counts _bytes_.  `VARCHAR(250)` can hold 250 _characters_ in whatever `CHARACTER SET` is is declared to be.  That will occupy _up to_ 2+3*250 bytes in the case of `utf8`.