# Best datatype to store two words?

Tags: mysql, sql, sqldatatypes

I have three words: `پرسیده شده` ,`ویرایش شده` ,`جواب داده شده`.

Also I have a column in the database which always contains one of words above. Which datatype do you recommend for that column?

Currently it is `varchar(13)`. But I'm doubt to use `char(13)` instead. What do you think?

Comment: This might be of interest: [MySQL varchar lengths and UTF-8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1997540/mysql-varchar-lengths-and-utf-8)

Comment: Enum is probably most efficient

Comment: @Strawberry http://komlenic.com/244/8-reasons-why-mysqls-enum-data-type-is-evil/

Answer (score 1):

**varchar** is the best choice.

**char** is recommended when the length of field is fixed.

Read the MySQL Docs: [The CHAR and VARCHAR Types](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/char.html)

Answer (score 0):

im vote for varchar because its cheaper and less processing consuming when getting values a lot of times.

in the otherwise, chat is more robust, but is more slow than varchar

Comment: In what way is `CHAR` "more robust"?  and "slower"?